# Computing probability [Inclusion-Exclusion?]

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In a toy box, suppose there are 22 marble balls (only blue or red) and 10 tennis balls (again, only blue or red). 4 of the tennis balls are blue, and 12 of the marble balls are red. If one ball is picked up randomly, determine the probability that the ball is either a tennis ball or red.

I am a beginner in probability but my guess is that it can be done by inclusion-exclusion.

P(T U R) = P(T) + P(R) - P(T&R) = (10/22) + (18/22) - (6/22)

Do I seem to be on the right track? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Easier approach is $~1~$ minus the probability that the ball is a blue marble, which is $~1 - \dfrac{10}{32}.$

Comment: That's smart. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use inclusion-exclusion (or consider the complement as in the comment by @user2661923) but your calculation doesn't look quite right to me. All the denominators should be $32$, not $22$, since that's the total number of balls.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much everyone :)

Ah, I see the problem in the denominator, thanks again :)

Comment: @Qas After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).